# Java how to override compareto for generic V

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm really struggling with this. I can't figure out why I can't compare the value with Node.value...

line:

```
if (value < currentNode.value) {
```

problem: Operator '<' cannot be applied to 'V','java.lang.Comparable'

```
public class BinaryTree<V extends Comparable<V>> {
    Node<V> root;

    public void addNode(V value) {
        Node newNode = new Node(value);

        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            Node<V> currentNode = root;
            Node<V> parent;

            while (true) {
                parent = currentNode;

                if (value.compareTo(currentNode.value) == -1) {
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;

                    if (currentNode == null) {
                        parent.left = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    currentNode = currentNode.right;

                    if (currentNode == null) {
                        parent.right = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public int compareTo(V v){
        if(this.V > v) return 1;
        if(this.V < v) return -1;
        else                   return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node should also have a generic type which extends comparable `Node<V extends Comparable<V>>` and should be initialized with that generic `Node<V> root` - this applies to all Node variables.

Comment: I have a generic node type if you're talking about a Node class. I added <V> to all Nodes but I still get the "error" my node class is as follows:                                                                                         class Node<V extends Comparable<V>> {

    V value;

    Node<V> left, right;


    public Node(V value) {

        this.value = value;

        left = null;

        right = null;

    }

    public V getValue() {

        return value;

    }
}

Comment: @max270500 switch '<' with compareTo(). You have overridden the compareTo method not the '<' operand.

Comment: I got it right now i think... i tried: if (value.compareTo(currentNode.value) == -1). however i now get the error in the overrideTo method: cannot resolve  symbol 'v'

Comment: @max270500 you can try changing `this.V` to `this.root.value`

Comment: @max270500 ok as a last try can you try deleting the whole compareTo method. The V class should have a default override for how to compare it's values if it extends Comparable.